# CakePHP Model->find('first') returns false when order specified

Tags: php, cakephp

In CakePHP 1.3, if I do, say:

```
$this->User->find('first');
```

I get a model item back. But if I add an order clause:

```
$this->User->find('first', array('order' => array('user.id' => 'asc')));
```

it returns false.

This is only affecting the server installation - both queries work as expected on my dev environment running the same CakePHP version, albeit on a later version of PHP.

Comment: Allow debug and please share the output of the SQL query and the error. Cakephp 1.3 is pretty old, why not using the new version? (assuming that there's new php and sql versions support)

Comment: Try changing user.id in User.id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your query is that you are not following the rules.

CakePHP models should be **UpperCamelCased**

So your query should be:

```
$this->User->find('first', array('order' => array('User.id' => 'asc')));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
$this->User->find('first', array('order' => array('User.id ASC')));
```

And do an debug(

```
$this->User->find('first', array('order' => array('User.id ASC'));
```

And see what it returns

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this is working fine on my local:

```
 $user= $this->User->find("first", array("order"=>"User.id ASC"));
 debug($user); //see what does it returns
```